# How to parametize Fourier series coefficients

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series, regression

How do I parametize and optimize coefficients of a fourier series of size n=200, I'm not so sure how to proceed with this linear regression clearly won't work.

I already have the coefficients of the Fourier series but I would like to parametize them further if you get what I mean, to reduce their mean square errors.

Comment: What does it mean to "parametrize" and "optimize" the coefficients of a Fourier series?????

Comment: I actually want to tweak the coefficients so It reduces the errors from it's current output and my desired results, without having to add more coefficients.

Comment: So you're looking to find the coefficients of the Fourier series, but with periods that are potentially not integer divisors of your domain?

Comment: @BarryCarter I already have the coefficients of the Fourier series but I would like to parametize them further if you get what I mean, to reduce their mean square errors.

Comment: @Smithy I'm not sure what you mean -- the Fourier coefficients are, by definition, the best fit you can get with periods that divide the length of your domain. My https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463481/continuous-fourier-transform-on-discrete-data-using-mathematica talks about continuous Fourier transforms and may help, but doesn't answer your question

Comment: @BarryCarter oh okay noted

Comment: You will need to make this question more specific to your problem at hand. As written, it is far too vague. You *have* to update the question. Answerers should not have to read the comment thread to understand your question.